# 401.1 errors with Windows Authentication IIS 8.5 Win 2012 R2, lots of detail no answers

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8, windows-authentication

Completely stumped at this one.  We've got an internal web server accessed by users for a variety of sites.  One of those requires Windows Authentication the site is http://caf.  ("caf" is an A record in DNS in our domain)

The server itself is set up for Windows Authentication:
[image: installed roles]

And the site is set up like this:

[image: Authentication]
[image: Advanced Settings]
[image: Providers]

Believe me, every permutation of the provider order, extended protection, and kerberos switch have been tried over the past few days of debugging.

After repeated prompting for name/password, the error that comes back is 401 Unauthorized.  The name and password are correct, have not been locked out, are being presented with the domain name, etc..

I turned on failed request tracing, and this is what comes out of it:

[image: Failed Request]

Detail here, but I've omitted some for brevity:

[image: trace1]
...
[image: trace2]
...
[image: trace3]

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on here?  Perhaps suggest a remedy?

Comment: I think this might be a Kerbos issue - http://forums.iis.net/t/1183613.aspx?How+to+resolve+the+issue+of+Integrated+windows+authentication+asking+username+and+password+in+Windows+Server+2008+R2+IIS+7+5+ Did you find resolution to it?

Comment: @Clinton Pierce, Has anyone have a resolution to this

Comment: I would also like to have an answer to this...

Answer (score 1):

This could be loop back issue, are you trying to access the IIS site from the same machine.

Try accessing the site from different machine in the LAN.

Comment: If disabling loopback check works, then what are alternative solutions? I don't want to disable loopback check on production server. Do I need to host sites on two different servers for it to work? Is there something I can do in DNS?